# Optimally traverse a DAG with weighted vertices in parallel

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

There is a graph where vertices represent pieces of code and edges represent dependencies between them. Additionally, each vertex has two numbers: how many threads the corresponding piece of code can use (1, 2, ..., or "as many as there are cores"), and how much time it is estimated to take if it gets that many threads (compared to others - for example, 1, 0.1 or 10). The idea is to run the pieces of code minding their dependencies in parallel, giving them such numbers of threads that the total execution time is the smallest.

Is there some existing algorithm which would do that or which I could use as a base?

So far I was thinking as follows. For example, we have 8 threads total (so NT = 8T) and the following graph.

```
  +----------------+         +----------------+
+-+ A: 0.2x, 1T    +----+    | F: 0.1x, 1T    |
| +---+------------+    |    +---+------------+
|     |                 |        |
| +---v------------+    |    +---v------------+
| | B: 0.1x, 2T    +-+  |    | G: 0.3x, NT    +-+
| +----------------+ |  |    +----------------+ |
|                    |  |                       |
| +----------------+ |  |    +----------------+ |
+-> C: 0.4x, 1T    | |  +----> H: 0.1x, 1T    | |
  +--+-------------+ |       +--+-------------+ |
+----+               |          |               |
| +----------------+ |       +--v-------------+ |
| | D: 0.1x, 1T    <-+       | J: 1.5x, 4T    <-+
| +--+-------------+         +-------+--------+
|    |                               |
| +--v-------------+                 |
+-> E: 1.0x, 4T    +------------+    |
  +----------------+            |    |
                             +--v----v--------+
                             + I: 0.01x, 1T   |
                             +----------------+
```

At task I we have 2 dependencies, E and J. As J dependencies, we have F-G and A-H. For E, A-C and A-B-D. To get to J, we need 0.3x on A-H and 0.4x on F-G, but G needs many threads for that. We could first run A and F in parallel (each with a single thread). Then we would run G with 7 threads and as A finishes, H with 1 thread. However there's also the E branch. Ideally, we would like it to be ready 0.5 later than J. In this case, it's quite easy because the longest path to E when we have already processed A takes 0.4 using one thread, and the other path takes less than that and uses just 2 threads - so we can run these calculations when J is running. But if, say, D took 0.6x, we would probably need to run it in parallel with G as well.

So I think I could start with the sink vertex and balance the weights of subgraphs on which it depends. But given these "N-thread" tasks, it's not particularly clear how. And considering that the x-numbers are just estimates, it would be good if it could make adjustments if particular tasks took more or less time than anticipated.

Comment: Can a task be run with fewer threads? For example, can `E` be run with 2 threads? And if so, how long does it take with 2 threads?

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, tasks may be given less threads than they requested. The scaling is linear I guess: if a task wants X threads to run for a given time, it will take twice as much time given X/2 threads.

Comment: This problem seems like a variation of the [rectangle packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Different_rectangles_in_a_rectangle) with a twist and a complication. The twist is that some of the rectangles ((B,E,G,J) in the example) can change shape. The complication is that there's a partial ordering between rectangles (related to [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)). Here's the [optimal solution to the example visualized as rectangle packing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QWWV.png). Bottom line, I don't see any easy solution.

Comment: Do you know Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) ? From looking briefly at the problem, it seems like you could describe it as a MILP and feed it to a solver.

Comment: @m.raynal How would you formulate MILP problem when one task needs to wait for the other to finish?

Comment: Basically by making the time dimension discrete, adding variables for start/end time for each node, and adding some more variables to enforce the dependencies of the graph. And of course by having a script writing the OPL file, or using an ILOG style interface. As often in MILP, we would end up with way more variables than in the original problem, but that's generally not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can model this problem as a [job shop scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) (flexible job shop problem in particular, where the machines are processors, and the jobs are slices of programs to be run).
First, you have to modify a bit your DAG, in order to transform it into another DAG which is the [disjunctive graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) representing your problem.
This transformation is very simple. For any node `i, t, nb_t` representing the job `i`, that need `t` seconds to be performed with 1 thread, and that can be parallelized into `nb_t` threads, do the following:
Replace `i, t, nb_t` by `nb_t` vertices `i_1, t/nb_t`, ..., `i_(nb_t), t/nb_t`. For each incoming/outgoing edge of the node `i`, create an incoming/outgoing edge from/to all the newly created nodes. Basically, we just split each job that can be parallelized into smaller jobs that can be handled by several processors (machines) simultaneously.
You then have your disjuntive graph, which is the input to the job shop problem.

Then, all you need to do is to solve this well-known problem, there are different options available ....
I would advice using a MILP solver, but from the small search I just did, it seems like many meta-heuristics can tackle the problem (simulated annealing, genetic programming, ...).

Comment: If you want some advices on how to solve the job shop problem with a LP solver, you can try and ask on the brand new [operations research](or.stackexchange.com) stack exchange :-)